# Triggering a Job on start up in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to get a new job to run every time my Jenkins restarts. I want to do this through "init.groovy" script. For example let's say if I restart my jenkins server it will execute a job that says "Hello world". And I have to create this job from my init.groovy script.

I have this code so far

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob

WorkflowJob job = Jenkins.instance.createProject(WorkflowJob, 'my-pipeline2')
```

now I don't know how to configure this job instance without getting into the GUI. I want to add pipeline scripts to it. Like echo "Hello world". And then I want to finally build this job. I want to do all that from this one init.groovy script. I couldn't find any solution to this over internet. So any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do you use Linux or windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have finally done this with the following groovy script.

```
#!groovy

import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import jenkins.install.*;
import hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob;

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

println "--> creating local user 'admin'"

def hudsonRealm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)
hudsonRealm.createAccount('admin','admin')
instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonRealm)

def strategy = new FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy()

instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)
instance.save()

jenkins = Jenkins.instance;

workflowJob = new WorkflowJob(jenkins, "workflow2");
jobName = "create-dsl-job2";
gitTrigger = new SCMTrigger("* * * * *");

dslProject = new hudson.model.FreeStyleProject(jenkins, jobName);
dslProject.addTrigger(gitTrigger);
jenkins.add(dslProject, jobName);
job = jenkins.getItem(jobName)
builders = job.getBuildersList()

hudson.tasks.Shell newShell = new hudson.tasks.Shell("echo \"Hello\" ")
builders.replace(newShell)

gitTrigger.start(dslProject, true);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also try the [Startup Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/startup-trigger-plugin/) plugin.

Once installed, go the Job that you want to trigger after startup and in the section 'Build Triggers', check 'Build when Jenkins first starts'

(This question may be old, but hope my answer helps someone)